# Run time complexity of countElements if T.Index is RandomAccessIndexType?

Tags: ios, string, swift

What is the run time complexity of the countElements function when counting characters of a `String`?

The documentation says:

> O(1) if T.Index is RandomAccessIndexType; O(N) otherwise.

What is a RandomAccessIndexType? Is `String` a RandomAccessIndexType?

Answer (score 2):

Accordingly to the documentation:

> An index that can be offset by an arbitrary number of positions, and can measure the distance to any reachable value, in O(1)

Swift strings (unfortunately) don't implement it. They use `BidirectionalIndexType` instead, which basically makes the string a bidirectional linked list, meaning that in order to reach character at position `n` from position `m` it navigates through all elements between them. As a result, the `countElements` function for strings has complexity O(n)

Comment: To add additional information, String is not a RandomAccessIndexType because String supports extended grapheme clusters, which means a string must be iterated to find an "element", which represents an entire grapheme cluster, not just a single grapheme (e.g. a combining character/accent etc).

Comment: Also because String is implemented in UTF-16 characters in plane 1 and above require two UTF-16 code units. Most Emoji are in plane 1. This is really no different than `NSString`. NSString’s `length` property has been renamed `utf16Count` when you access it on a Swift string. The `NSString` `length` property returns the number of UTF-16 code units (`unichar`), not the number of characters.